# How to navigate through a paginated list until find a text with Serenity-JS?

Tags: protractor, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-js

I need to assert that an element I created was added to a list, but it is added at the end of it and it is paginated.

I'm thinking of navigating through each page by calling another task this way:

```js
export class CheckItem implements Task {
  static afterCreated(): CheckItem {
    return new CheckItem();
  }

  performAs(actor: PerformsTasks & UsesAbilities): PromiseLike<void> {
    return TakeNotes.as(actor).read('item-name')
      .then((itemName: string) => actor
        .attemptsTo(
          NavigateThroughItemList.untilFinds(itemName),
        ));
  }
}
```

I need to implement `NavigateThrougItemList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution by using a recursive call. Maybe there is a better solution for this, but this one worked for me.

```js
export class NavigateThroughItemList implements Task {
  static untilFinds(itemName: string): NavigateThroughItemList {
    return new NavigateThroughItemList(itemName);
  }

  constructor(private itemName: string) {
  }

  @step('{0} navigates through the list until #itemName is found')
  performAs(actor: PerformsTasks): PromiseLike<void> {
    return actor.attemptsTo(
      See.if(Text.ofAll(ItemList.items), include(this.itemName)),
    ).catch(() => actor
      .attemptsTo(
        See.if(
          WebElement.of(ItemList.nextButton),
          isEnabled(),
        ),
      )
      .then(() => actor
        .attemptsTo(
          Click.on(ItemList.nextButton),
        ))
      // Looping until it finds the item
      .then(() => this.performAs(actor)));
  }
}
```